# facebook android, which permission is needed to access user's id?

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

In Android, which permission is needed to access user's Facebook id?

```
LoginButton authButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("permission", "permission"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Public Profile and Friend List** permission, see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/).